# For what parameter values is an interpolated cubic a monotone function?

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I want a monotonic differentiable function $f(x)$ such that, for some $0 < a < 1 < b$:

- $f(x) = x$ for all $x \le a$
- $f(x) = 1$ for all $x \ge b$

So basically the problem boils down to two steps:

- Choosing values of $a$ and $b$ (these will become user-adjustable parameters in a computer program)
- Defining $f(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$

Ignoring the monotonicity constraint, the simplest way to find such a $f(x)$ is to interpolate a cubic polynomial: $g(x) = mx^3 + nx^2 + px + q$, so that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$, using the system of equations:

- $g(a) = ma^3 + na^2 + pa + q = a$
- $g(b) = mb^3 + nb^2 + pb + q = b$
- $g'(a) = 3ma^2 + 2na + p = 1$
- $g'(b) = 3mb^2 + 2nb + p = 0$

Unfortunately, the resulting $g(x)$ could have a local maximum in $(a,b)$, making $f(x)$ not monotonic. Is there some easy way to characterize the region in the $AB$ plane consisting of those points for which $g(x)$ doesn't have a local maximum in $(a,b)$?

**Edit:** When I insert a word in the middle of a sentence, I should re-read the whole sentence. :-p